# Parents teaching children or children teaching parents?

Tags: sources-mekorot, children-parenting, passover-seder-hagada, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, mesorah-tradition

Regarding והגדת לבנך, *and you shall tell to your children* (Shemos 13:8), on Pesach night:

1) What is the ***mitzvah*** of והגדת לבנך and how does one fulfill it according to *halacha*?

2a) Why do yeshivos give out *divrei torah* to children to say at the Seider, if the ***mitzvah*** of Pesach night is והגדת לבנך?

2b) Are there any *poskim* that oppose yeshivos giving out *divrei torah* to children to say at the Seider? If there are, who are they?

Comment: I'm not voting to close as Q 2a seems quite clear. 1 and 2b, however, are not. I have no idea who has voted to close, yet, but, perhaps a comment explaining why, would help us.

Comment: @DanF: Do you understand what I'm asking?

Comment: With the edits that you made, yes, it does seem clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @DanF: I'm happy and you're welcome. What surprises me is that no one has ever thought about this or even asked about this issue beforehand.

Comment: Questions 2a and 3 in the current version look like rhetorical, rather than interrogative, questions .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has various aspects, but as they are all related, I hope that my answer addresses all the items in some fashion.

Q1 - You may want to read [Ohr HaChaim's commentray](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14126&st=&pgnum=180&hilite=) on the verse you cited. While not directly indicating what the halacha is, he implies that from the wording, the concept is that the parents should tell the story of Pesach at night specifically when Matzah and Maror are in front of him. Keep in mind that there was no concept of a "Seder" at the time the Torah was given. What is also apparent from the placement of the verse, is that the previous verse says that you should eat Matzah for seven days, and a key phrase in this verse (the one you cited) is "ba'avur zeh" - because of THIS - meaning it is an answer to why we eat Matzah - at least, immediately. Rash"i also explains that this is an answer to the wicked son, a concept developed later, as the 4 sons are part of the Seder.

Now, to answer the rest of your questions - you raise a valid point, and this has been addressed in the past. I refer you to [this article](http://www.lookstein.org/online_journal.php?id=16) . Within it, he mentions these points:

- Citing Mishnah Pesachim, 10th Chapter, it says:

> When the second cup of wine is poured, it is expected that the child,
>   curious about what has transpired, will begin questioning. If the
>   child is not aware enough to notice the differences, his father is to
>   prod him with a series of observations – “Look at how different
>   tonight is from all other nights!” The continuation of the Mishnaic
>   description states that the father should teach his child according to
>   the child's ability to understand, and suggests that the teaching
>   begin with an exploration of how bad things were before they got
>   better. Finally, the Mishnah adds that part of the seder should
>   include an expounding of the Torah portion beginning with the
>   description of the wandering Aramean.
>
> Let us consider what preparation this child had for this event. Was
>   the child trained in advance to memorize a series of questions he
>   would perform for the assembled? Apparently not, as the Mishnah seems
>   to suggest that the questions are spontaneous. In fact, there is no
>   fixed text for the questions the child asks, only for the father whose
>   child has failed to notice the changes at the table.

So, it seems clear that you are correct that the commandment is for the parents to teach children and not in reverse.

The author suggests the following:

> Creating a contemporary educational program for the seder needs to
>   focus on the parents as much as on the children, restoring the
>   parent's role as a key transmitter of an oral tradition, and should
>   account for the essentially non-text component of the evening. In the
>   younger grades, model seders should be held for parents, and not their
>   children. Educational packets should present parents with the tools
>   for leading a seder which positions the children at the center of an
>   inquisitive process directed by the parents; as their children grow,
>   parents need to be taught how to encourage their children to ask more
>   substantive questions.

I also recommend reading the [related blog](http://lookstein.org/lookjed/read.php?1,5185,5194#msg-5194) to the article, as some of the writers offer supplemental ideas. In one of the emails, the author of the article adds this story:

> I have been told that in the late Forties and Fifties Rav Avigdor
>   Miller  would tell the members of his Shul that they should make sure
>   at the Seder  to listen to what their children had learned in yeshiva.
>   During those  years the majority of the members of his Shul did not
>   have extensive  yeshiva educations.
>
> On the other hand, a grandson of his told me that at his Seder Rav
>   Miller  would go through the Haggadah, and focus on explaining only a
>   few key  points. When a grandchild would say "My rebbe said," Rav
>   Miller would  smile and say, "Let's wait until later to hear what he
>   said." He would  then move on, continuing the Haggadah narrative. The
>   grandson told me that  he never recalled "later" coming.

In summary - you raised an important question, and I hope the article addresses your concerns. With that, wishes for a Happy and educational Pesach.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm even more interested to know what our Gedolim (i.e. Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky) have to say on this matter.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah I haven't seen his brother, Rav Binyamin, in a while. Next time I see him, B"N, I'll try to ask him what he or what his father, a"h, thinks, if your specific to the Kaminetzky "clan".