# Children saying Divrei torah at the Pesach seider

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, passover, children-parenting, passover-seder-hagada

Are there any Gedolim who oppose the concept of children saying Divrei torah to their parents at the Pesach Seider?

Comment: Interesting question. Why do you thing there might be Gedolim who would oppose this?

Comment: Tircha d'tziburra, perhaps? @Fred (*though if so, it should probably be [edit]ed into the question*)

Comment: You asked this already! http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55157/759 Don't reask questions just because you didn't get an answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Agreed. Actually, I answered him in your linked question!

Comment: The haggadah of the gedolim cites the minhag of Rav Mordechai Kamenetztsky who would have only the youngest say the questions and would then go through the magid without adding anything else. Any divrei torah would be either during the meal (while waiting for the next course or after the seder). This is from memory)

Answer (score 1):

[From here](http://matzav.com/rav-schachter-teach-the-poshut-pshat):

> [the moderator] asked the rabbonim in which area do they see the most mistakes being made with regard to Pesach observance.
>
> Rav [Hershel] Shechter responded that earlier, it had been asked **how much time people should allow their children to spend on the sheets that they prepared in school.**
>
> **“I think that that’s a major problem,”** said Rav Schachter. “[At] all the different yeshivos and all the day schools, the rabbeim a lot of times teach the children gematrios and roshei teivos and pshetlach and vehi shemada…[that] it means this and it means that. They don’t tell them the poshut p’shat. I think it is a problem with Chumash as well…they teach all the children p’shetlach on all the pesukim.
>
> “I think we should try to straighten out the yeshivos and the chinuch, and the day schools…should teach the poshut pshat, without the gematrios and without the roshei teivos. They should know what the pirush hamillos is. **We shouldn’t have the children eat up so much time with all these roshei teivos and p’shetlach. And then we finish the Afikoman after chatzos and we finish the Arbah Kosos after chatzos.** They should be…trained to say over the poshut p’shat.”